# asp.net Make a listView row clickable without a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, listview

I want to make a listview row clickable without using a button.
the listview is filled with data out of a database so putting a onclick methode directly on the tr isnt a option.

I found this tread: http://forums.asp.net/t/1419161.aspx

But i get the error: " registerforeventvalidation can only be called during render()" at line:

```
     string script = this.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(btn, "", true);
```

This is fixable by setting " enableEventValidation="false" " at @Page directive.

Now my question:

- Am i doing something wrong?
- is it a bad thing to do to turn eventValidation off?
- is there a better way of doing this? if so how?

i prefer listview but if there is a better way that involves some other grid like control i would also like to hear that.

i am making this in asp.net VB.net but c# example is also fine.

Thanks!

Comment: You can easily make a row clickable even if the item is filled from a db. Why do you think you can't?

Comment: You still can embed an onclick event on the <tr>. Add a method to get the url to go to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this from a database. In the example below clicking on the row will call a javascript function called evalItem, and pass the "Publisher" field from the data item for the row bound to the listview.

```
 <ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="clsGroupRowSelectable" onclick='evalItem(&#39;<%# Eval("Publisher").ToString() %>&#39;);'>
       <td><%# Eval("Number") %>' /></td>
    </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```